# What is the RPN operator defined in PSTricks to convert an infix expression to the postfix one?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

The following code does not compile as I failed to convert the abscissa from infix to postfix.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

% defining an RPN operator that converts Infix Cartesian to Postfix Polar
\pstVerb{/ICtoPP {tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end exch cvx /x ED cvx /y ED y x RadtoDeg PtoC} def }


\begin{document}
\def\Infix#1{(2^(#1/10))}% needs outer parentheses (...)
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{\Infix{x}} 
  \qdisk(! (3*Pi/2) \Infix{(3*Pi/2)} ICtoPP){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure `AlgToPs` converts only a single expression. If both coordinates are given with infix notation, you must invoke it twice. And for convenience, pstricks has a procedure `AlgParser` which is defined as `tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end`.

I also had a problem with the parenthesis in the `\qdisk` node expression. The following works:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

% defining an RPN operator that converts Infix Cartesian to Postfix Polar
\pstVerb{/ICtoPP {AlgParser cvx exec exch AlgParser cvx exec RadtoDeg PtoC} def }


\begin{document}
\def\Infix#1{(2^(#1/10))}% needs outer parentheses (...)
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{\Infix{x}}
  \def\myval{(3*Pi/2) }
  \qdisk(! \myval \Infix{\myval} ICtoPP){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. I also tried that way, however the error thrown by the parenthesis problem  was to cryptic for me. I find your solution more elegant.

Comment: Is it safe to rename my operator `ICtoPP` to `IC2PP`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'safe'? It may overwrite an existing operator with this name, but I don't think it exists.

Comment: I meant that is it safe to use numbers inserted between letters when defining an name for PS operators or variables or constants?

Comment: Yes, citing from the Redbook: „Any token that consists entirely of regular characters and cannot be interpreted as a number is treated as a name object (more precisely, an executable name). All characters except delimiters and white-space characters can appear in names, including characters ordinarily considered to be punctuation.
The following are examples of valid names:
`abc` `Offset` `$$` `23A` `13−456` `a.b` `$MyDict` `@pattern`“

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the `infix-RPN` package (which is used by the `pst-infixplot` package), even if that's not exactly a PSTricks operator. 
The following MWE does the job.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-infixplot}

% defining an RPN operator that converts Infix Cartesian to Postfix Polar
\pstVerb{/ICtoPP {tx@AlgToPs begin AlgToPs end exch cvx /x ED cvx /y ED y x RadtoDeg PtoC} def }

\begin{document}
\def\Infix#1{(2^(#1/10))}% needs outer parentheses (...)
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\psplot[algebraic,polarplot,plotpoints=100]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{\Infix{x}} 
 \def\abscissa{(3*Pi/2)}
 \infixtoRPN{\abscissa}
 \qdisk(! \RPN \Infix{\abscissa} ICtoPP){2pt}
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 as well even though it is not what I am looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\Infix#1{2^(#1/10)}% 
\def\QDisk#1#2{\pnode(+#1,\Infix{#1}){foo}%
  \qdisk(! \psGetNodeCenter{foo} foo.y foo.x RadToDeg PtoC){#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{\Infix{x}}
  \QDisk{3*Pi/2}{2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I chose Christoph's answer as it is more relevant to my question.